# Seeking radial equation to form a specific shape

Tags: geometry

I have a formula to produce a shape with the following properties when plotted as a radial graph across $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$:

- The curve reaches minimum distance from the origin when $\theta = \pi$
- The curve reaches max distance at $\theta = 0$
- Slicing the curve through the origin produces a cut of the same length regardless of the angle of the slice (this is the important part)

So far I have the following formula for the above:

$$F\left(\theta\right)=\frac{\left|\theta-\pi\right|}{\pi}$$

The produced shape is similar to a palm leaf or the blade of the Spades suit marker, with minimum distance at 0.  It works well for the first part of my problem, but for the next step I would like to find a variation of the above that allows for a smooth transition between the above and a circle with a diameter the same as the cut length above.  Unfortunately the math is a little beyond me... I'm a database programmer, not a mathematician.

Can anyone help with such a formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply try a linear combination of the two curves:
$$
F(\theta)=s\cdot{|\theta-\pi|\over\pi}+(1-s)\cdot{1\over2},
\quad\text{for any $s\in[0,1].$}
$$
This gives you the possibility to generate all possible transitions between the two curves, the length of the cut being $1$ in all cases.

Comment: Oh dear.  Now I feel foolish... this is a simple linear interpolation between the formula I provided and the circle I'm aiming for.  Now I feel a little silly... thank you :)